Related to sign convention used in gravitational potential energy
In the formula for potential energy, why don't we take value of $g$ in $mgh$ as negative because it acts opposite to the displacement the value is taken 9.8m/s² but why not -9.8m/s²

Hint: prove$$\frac{-GMm}{R+h}-\frac{-GMm}{R}\approx +mgh,,g=\frac{GM}{R^2}.$$

$F_r=-dU/dr$ Since gravitational force is downward, potential energy must increase upward. Another way to think about it is that the potential energy of a falling object must decrease as its kinetic energy increases in order to conserve energy.


why don't we take value of $g$ in $mgh$ as negative

Because $g$ in $mgh$ is the magnitude of the acceleration due to gravity, not the acceleration vector.
As you correctly pointed out the acceleration is $$\vec g=-9.8 m/s^{2}\
\hat j$$
The change in gravitational potential energy is the negative of the work done by gravity (a conservative force).
Thus
$$\Delta U =-\vec F_{g}\cdot \vec h
=-m\vec {g}\cdot \vec h=-m(-9.8)\hat {j}\cdot {h}\hat j=m(9.8)h=mgh$$
Where $g$ is the magnitude of the acceleration due to gravity.
Hope this helps.

Take sign convention wherever  you want
But the other sign conventions change as wel
If displacement is negative downwards g is negative
If it positive g is positive
